# How to select an image URL using Regex for Grep in bash script?

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I have a text file, where I need to select URLs for images using bash script. 
An example of a line from the text file:

```
<icon height="36" width="36" density="ldpi" src="res/icon/android/ldpi.png"/>
```

I wrote the following script using Regex:

```
echo $line | grep -E -o "[^\"\'=\s]+\.(jpe?g|png|gif)"
```

An output shows: `/icon/android/ldpi.png`
However, I need: `res/icon/android/ldpi.png`

Can anyone help to fix the problem and make the right output like `res/icon/android/ldpi.png` ?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: `\s` is not whitespace matching pattern, it matches ``\`` and `s` and as `res` contains `s` it is not matched. Try `"[^\"]+\.(jpe?g|png|gif)"` or `"[^\"'=[:space:]]+\.(jpe?g|png|gif)"`

Comment: Depending on your "text file" (looks like it could be XML?), and your criteria for deciding whether something is an image (value of `src` attribute, and/or any value ending in a typical image extension?) you might end up with a more robust solution using a parser, rather than a plain text tool such as `sed` or `grep`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, `\s` is not recognized by `grep` as a whitespace matching pattern, it matches `\` and `s` and as `res` contains `s` it is not matched.

You may  try

```
grep -Eo "[^\"'=[:space:]]+\.(jpe?g|png|gif)" <<< "$line"
```

Or, use Bash regex matching:

```
rx="src=([\"'])([^\"']+\.(jpe?g|png|gif))\1"
if [[ "$line" =~ $rx ]]; then
  echo "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}";
fi;
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/h93Ric)

The `src=([\"'])([^\"']+\.(jpe?g|png|gif))\1` pattern matches

- `src=` - a literal substring
- `([\"'])` - Group 1: a `"` or `'`
- `([^\"']+\.(jpe?g|png|gif))` - Group 2 (this value is accessible via `"${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"` after a match is found): any 1+ chars other than `"` and `'` followed with `.` and `jpeg`, `jpg`, `png`, `gif`
- `\1` - Group 1 value.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `awk`, you can do:

```
awk -F'src=' 'NF>1 {split($2,a,"\"");print a[2]}' file
res/icon/android/ldpi.png
```

It will print all data between `""` if it comes after `src=`

If it needs to only be jpg/gif/png extension?

```
awk -F'src=' 'NF>1 && $2~/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)/ {split($2,a,"\"");print a[2]}' file
res/icon/android/ldpi.png
```